# MySQL table creation with Spring + Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring, object-persistence

We came across the following situation.

***Please note that I know reserved words should not be used for table names, but I'm asking the question anyway out of curiosity more than anything.***

We are using Spring + Hibernate to manage our database. I am adding a new model to the database called *Group*. So, I define my model as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
public class Group {
    ...
}
```

Now, the problem is, when recreating the tables, the SQL that gets generated looks as follows:

```
create table group (...)
```

This unfortunately is not allowed in MySQL since `group` is a reserved word. The correct SQL should be:

```
create table `group`(...)
```

Is there any way for me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force Hibernate to escape identifiers by doing this:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-quotedidentifiers

Basically, you can quote them yourself, and then Hibernate will use the appropriate quoting technique according to the dialect

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement your own org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy, which add the backticks to all tables. -- But I am sure that this abuse the NamingStrategy class.